# docker-compose load multiple env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to make docker-compose (v2.12.2) load env variables from both `.env` and `.env.local`

I tried the method mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7326#issuecomment-1252426491):

```bash
docker-compose --env-file <(cat "./.env" && ([ -f "./.env.local" ] && cat "./.env.local" || echo '')) up -d
```

But it seems that no envs are loaded and plenty of warnings are thrown:

```
WARN[0000] The "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "PGADMIN_HOST_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
...
```

Don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

```bash
vim <(cat "./.env" && ([ -f "./.env.local" ] && cat "./.env.local" || echo ''))
```

vim shows that two env files are concatenated correctly:

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=example@example.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=example
PGADMIN_HOST_PORT=8080

PGADMIN_HOST_PORT=8081
```

OS: centOS 7

Comment: Are these variables in `.env` or `.env.local` file?

Comment: @AbhishekS Yes,`vim <(cat "./.env" && ([ -f "./.env.local" ] && cat "./.env.local" || echo ''))` can open this file correctly

Comment: Remove your existing containers and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.17, the `--env-file` flag can be used in multiple occurrences to select more than one env file. Hacking is no longer needed.

Ref: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7326#issuecomment-1446246464

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a little script like this:
[image]

I have created two test files with the image and version.
In the command shown i create a test3 file which combines those two and uses it in the docker-compose as --env-file, afterwards test3 gets deleted again.

Note: test3 does not get deleted if there is a problem starting the docker container.